# Impossible to load url in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, url

I have tried recently to load a url dataset by using a pandas 
from this here: [flag's dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/flags/flag.data)

My code was:

```
enter code here
Import pandas as pd
dataset= pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/flags/flag.data')
dataset.head()
```

Everything should work normally but I have an error message. I have tried to understand as best I can could the message.. but I failed. Here the message:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-13064d485dcd> in <module>()
```

Comment: Do you consistently get this error, or does it work when you re-run the code? I was able to read the URL without issue

Answer (score 0):

At first you should make a request to get data and then you can read it.
The following code may be helpfull.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/flags/flag.data"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```